# external HDMI monitor turns off after a few minutes

Tags: 14.04, hdmi, monitor

When connecting my 14.04 Ubuntu laptop with HDMI to my TV, the image is turned off after a few minutes, even when connected to the power. I then move the mouse and the image returns.

**How can I prevent the monitor from turning off?**
Notice the laptop does not go into sleep mode, just turns off the monitor

Answer (score 1):

When inactive, Ubuntu turns off the screen after a while. To change this, open **Settings > Brightness & Lock** and change the **Turn screen off when inactive** to **Never**